# Using multiple cores to unpack a deb file in dpkg/gdebi/apt

Tags: dpkg, deb, archive, compression, gdebi

I often need to test a deb package install in which the extraction step takes quite a bit of time.

I've noticed that gdebi only (seems) to use a single core for the extraction, but it looks like [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313242/utilizing-multi-core-for-targzip-bzip-compression-decompression) compression programs can use multiple cores. Is there any way to make the extraction of deb files use multiple cores?